# How is the Fancybox License meant to be used?

Tags: fancybox, license-key

There is no relevant documentation of how the license key is to be used on the site or on GitHub. Is it meant to be embedded as a HTML Comment or in the JavaScript as a comment?

- http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/3/#license
- https://github.com/fancyapps/fancybox/issues/1032

Comment: This issue might also be related to your problem: https://github.com/fancyapps/fancybox/issues/1548

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jut keep it, there is no need to put/use it anywhere. Obviously, if you would have to do something specific, then it would be stated.